# Where does AWS Amplify store its resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I've just been looking at modifying an Amplify App in order to achieve multi-region deployment. While doing so I was hoping to figure out more about how it works under the hood. From everything I've read the process seems to be -> build the website -> store in S3 -> create a Cloudformation stack -> deploy.

I can't see any of these resources being created though, am very confused over where the front-end code actually rests once built, and have wasted a few hours searching without any luck. I'm hoping someone is able to enlighten me. My two questions are:

1. What resources does Amplify actually use for the front-end/website, and why can't I find them?
2. Where does Amplify store the actual website (javascript, html, css etc)?

Comment: Are you looking in the right region? What have you created on your AWS Amplify app? [auth for example is cognito](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/).

Comment: In cloudfront and S3 (two places where I was expecting to be able to see something) I am unable to select a region (I'm forced to use global). I'm not sure what you mean by what have I created on the amplify app, but it's a vue app, cognito has been configured separately, and access is provided by supplying the urls and pool ids using a .env file postfixed with the relevant environment.

Comment: AWS Amplify has Cognito available natively FYI.

Comment: Yeah, this is the first time I've looked into this side of the build. It basically hasn't been touched for over 2 years since some contractors set it up. I'll look into the feasibility of switching it over though. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

A cloudFormation stack would be created to manage the resources needed by your App. So if you can't find them maybe you are in the wrong region.

Where does Amplify store the actual website?
This will be stored in the Amazon CloudFront distribution associated with your app.

Comment: The only region available for me to select in cloudfront is 'global', within Amplify I have selected the London region. There is only one distribution in cloudfront, and this is for an unrelated domain last modified in september 2020. I think this is something leftover from the initial setup by the contractors.

Comment: I'd go to the AWS Amplify, click on the project name, click "backend", find the environment, and the list of resources created with it.

Comment: Ah thanks, I should probably refine my question. The backend is built separately by a codepipeline which runs in parallel. I'm looking for the front end code/configuration though.

Comment: See if there are any connected branches to the environment? Go to App Settings (Left Panel) then General. Scroll to the bottom.

Comment: There are lots of branches, all set to auto-build. The configuration all works, and has for years been deploying test, staging, and live environments, as well as per-branch front end environments. I'm getting the sense that this is just me? Do you find all your front end code in S3? I'm going to have a go at setting up a fresh app and see if it's something to do with the way it's been configured.