# Where does AWS Amplify store the frontend artifacts?

Tags: aws-amplify

I have been struggling to find where the frontend artifacts (html,css,js) are being stored when using AWS Amplify? I have successfully managed to find a S3 Bucket with all my backend related code such as the Lambda function but I cannot seem to understand where is the frontend build stored after running yarn build.

I looked around and found this question which has not been answered yet : [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75059405/where-does-aws-amplify-store-its-resources#_=_), the sole answer there says that the frontend artifacts are stored in a CloudFront instance but I am facing the same problem when accessing CloudFront as the OP (only region Central is available) and nothing is shown.

I tried to locate the artifacts in the Build logs and got across this [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fHFN.png), which successfully downloads the whole build.

However, it is still unclear to me where that build is being stored. Any clearance would be appreciated.